# Point based gluing window doesn't open

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to overlay two STL/PLY...-files with point-based gluing. I first glued the first mesh and then tried to align the second mesh with point-based gluing. But when I press this button the new window for selecting the points doesn't open and the program is blocked afterward that I have to close it with the task manager.
The strange thing is that when I click on it the typical sound is heard, like when you have a dialog box that has to be answered first to continue. But this dialog box or the window for point-based gluing is not visible.
I am really confused.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I'm working with meshlab version 2020.09 and can't reproduce your problem. Which version of meshlab are you using? Can you describe better which steps are you using to glue the meshes?